# How to print Contactgroup or contact with Host performance output data in Nagios

Tags: nagios

Am trying to extract monitoring results for hosts configured in nagios in a output file.  Changing "process-host-perfdata" command in /object/command.cfg. 
Can I populate Contactgroup information along with host related data? If yes, please help how this can be done.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that can be done. In fact you can configure Nagios to output any macros. Look for the below in your Nagios.cfg file

```
host_perfdata_file_template=[HOSTPERFDATA]\t$TIMET$\t$HOSTNAME$\t$HOSTEXECUTIONTIME$\t$HOSTOUTPUT$\t$HOSTPERFDATA$
```

Add the macros you want in the performance data output. You can also change the format etc if you want. You can find the macro list on Nagios documentation. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but that doesnt answer my question.

Comment: Am able to get any information from any Host related macro.

Comment: As you wrote above, HOSTNAME, HOSTEXECUTIONTIME, or other Host associated fields can be taken out in a straightforward manner. Am not able to find the way to get "contact_groups" information assocaited with hosts. Below is my host config, query os how to get ABCadmins value along with other details... define host{
       host_name      ABC
       alias          ABC
       address        xx.xx.xx.xx
          use        linux-server
        contact_groups   ABCadmins
}.